# Can Opera Mini or Mobile be configured to set the page title as the subject when sharing as email?

Tags: browser, opera-mini, opera-browser

Can Opera Mini or Mobile be configured to set the page title as the subject when sharing as email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - no. There are advanced options accessible by typing the URL `opera:advanced` , but most of those deal with the rendering engine.